# How are global variables handled in JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have to use JNI for a Java and C++ project, I got a quick overview of the subject, but one question arise : what if the C++ function I'm trying to call from within the Java code references a Global Variable (in the .cpp file) ? JNI can't call it directly, the global variables have to be loaded, and be in the same address as the function. So how is this done ?

Answer (score 1):

JNI doesn't have anythung to do with it. The variable is there in the .cpp file, the C++ function uses it, it compiles and links, period.

Comment: Does the global variables persist between Java to native calls?

Comment: @zeitgeist, yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks @Quirin. I guess only dynamically allocated memory in the native code needs special care in JNI because of garbage collection then.